# Using NEsper to read LogFiles for reporting purposes

Tags: complex-event-processing, logfile, nesper

We are evaluating NEsper. Our focus is to monitor data quality in an enterprise context. In an application we are going to log every change on a lot of fields - for example in an "order". So we have fields like

- Consignee name
- Consignee street
- Orderdate

....and a lot of more fields. As you can imagine the log files are going to grow big.

Because the data is sent by different customers and is imported in the application, we want to analyze how many (and which) fields are updated from "no value" to "a value" (just as an example).

I tried to build a test case with just with the fields

- order reference
- fieldname
- fieldvalue

For my test cases I added two statements with context-information. The first one should just count the changes in general per order:

```
epService.EPAdministrator.CreateEPL("create context RefContext partition by Ref from LogEvent");
var userChanges = epService.EPAdministrator.CreateEPL("context RefContext select count(*) as x, context.key1 as Ref from LogEvent");
```

The second statement should count updates from "no value" to "a value":

```
epService.EPAdministrator.CreateEPL("create context FieldAndRefContext partition by Ref,Fieldname from LogEvent");
var countOfDataInput = epService.EPAdministrator.CreateEPL("context FieldAndRefContext SELECT context.key1 as Ref, context.key2 as Fieldname,count(*) as x from pattern[every (a=LogEvent(Value = '') -> b=LogEvent(Value != ''))]");
```

To read the test-logfile I use the csvInputAdapter:

```
CSVInputAdapterSpec csvSpec = new CSVInputAdapterSpec(ais, "LogEvent");
csvInputAdapter = new CSVInputAdapter(epService.Container, epService, csvSpec);
csvInputAdapter.Start();
```

I do not want to use the update listener, because I am interested only in the result of all events (probably this is not possible and this is my failure).

So after reading the csv (csvInputAdapter.Start() returns) I read all events, which are stored in the statements NewEvents-Stream.

Using 10 Entries in the CSV-File everything works fine. Using 1 Million lines it takes way to long. I tried without EPL-Statement (so just the CSV import) - it took about 5sec. With the first statement (not the complex pattern statement) I always stop after 20 minutes - so I am not sure how long it would take.

Then I changed my EPL of the first statement: I introduce a group by instead of the context.

```
select Ref,count(*) as x from LogEvent group by Ref
```

Now it is really fast - but I do not have any results in my NewEvents Stream after the CSVInputAdapter comes back...

**My questions:**

1. Is the way I want to use NEsper a supported use case or is this the root cause of my failure?
2. If this is a valid use case: Where is my mistake? How can I get the results I want in a performant way?
3. Why are there no NewEvents in my EPL-statement when using "group by" instead of "context"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To 1), yes

To 2) this is valid, your EPL design is probably a little inefficient. You would want to understand how patterns work, by using filter indexes and index entries, which are more expensive to create but are extremely fast at discarding unneeded events.
Read: 
http://esper.espertech.com/release-7.1.0/esper-reference/html_single/index.html#processingmodel_indexes_filterindexes and also
http://esper.espertech.com/release-7.1.0/esper-reference/html_single/index.html#pattern-walkthrough
Try the "previous" perhaps. Measure performance for each statement separately.
Also I don't think the CSV adapter is optimized for processing a large file. I think CSV may not stream.

To 3) check your code? Don't use CSV file for large stuff. Make sure a listener is attached.